# Microsoft Bot Framework: Smilies in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are working on a cross-platform bot. We intent to handle smilies in MS Teams.
How to handle user entered smilies in MS Teams in bot framework?

Comment: Could you please try added [hex values for emojis](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)? Here is code snippet: `MessageFactory.Text($" &#x1F642; &#x1F602;")`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the actions a user can take on a message, like smile/thumbsup/etc. If so, those are called "Reactions" and you can read about it at the bottom of this page: [Handle Bot Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#reactions).

You don't mention if you're using [.net (C#)](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/25.message-reaction) or [Node](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.message-reaction), but I've put links to a sample for both.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry I forgot to mention: I am using C#.However, I am not looking for the reactions. I am interested in the messages sent by the user like :               
Bot:Hi Shaik, how can I help you today?
Shaik:    (smile)
This smile is selected from the icons given below.